# HTTP 403 Server failed to authenticate the request when downloading Blob image from azure

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm getting the above error when trying to donload an image from Azure Blob Storage in a UWP Windows 10 app. Full error is

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Its the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363906/azure-storage-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request)

Im using WindowsAzure.Storage version 6.0.0 and my app fails on the following method

```
public async Task<string> DownloadImageFromBlob(string resourceName)
    {
        BlobContinuationToken token = null;
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(resourceName);

        try
        {
            StorageFile file;
            var imageFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Secrets.BlobImageDirectory, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            file = await imageFolder.CreateFileAsync(resourceName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                //HTTP error 403 on the line below
                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fileStream);
                return blob.Name;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

The weird thing is this is standard code and worked perfectly in Windows 8.1 universal app but fails in Windows 10 UWP. I have no idea why?

**UPDATE 1:**
Starting a brand new UWP project with the above code works ok. So it isnt a Windows 10 issue but project specific.

Digging deeper into the error message reveals the following

> The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'HNMOq8xg4P/y+KpCz0bTEJVaUylV5zJUe7gl6Dey6HU=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWed, 22 Apr 2015 07:58:59 GMT\r\n\r\n0x8D24AE9533BAAA3\r\n\r\n\r\nx-ms-client-request-id:e7cf3a53-8bf1-4eef-b874-32ca126db514\r\nx-ms-date:Tue, 27 Oct 2015 09:20:00 GMT\r\nx-ms-version:2015-04-05\r\n/[]my storage account]/[my storage container]/Brownies%201.jpg'.

I note the old date of 22 Apr 2015 and have no idea where this date is created

**UPDATE 2**
Further testing shows its exactly the same problem as linked question. Runs first time on UWP app then exception

Comment: Just curious, why *isn't* this a duplicate of the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363906/azure-storage-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request)? From the [comments there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363906/azure-storage-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request#comment52601600_32364457), it appears that Win 10 is not supported yet.

Comment: I cant believe that something as simple as downloading a blob wouldn't be supported for Win10? It is a duplicate but there doesnt appear any viable fix on the linked question so was hoping someone from MSFT might see the new one ;)

Comment: Well, in the linked question, Microsoft confirmed that universal apps are not supported. The accepted answer has a link to a bug report on github. I can't speak for MS, but I'm guessing that they don't have anything to tell you since the bug is still open at this time.